# Custom Content Creation and retrieval in to pages dynamically using Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

We are looking to create Custom Content Types for the content where we want our site to be dynamically handled and be editable through Orchard Admin UIs,

and to load the content we created into Pages (thinking of having customized Layout.cshtml files)

Can someone explain how this can be done using  Orchard with examples.

Comment: Have you read through the documentation at http://orchardproject.net/? What other documentation/tutorials have you read? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Yes, Have read the documentation , but it does not specify how the newly created content can be retrieved in to a custom created layout location.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to create widgets. Hard to say from the question however as it is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you get hold onto the Orchard content manager, you would be able to access contents and their parts(within controller action or a driver)

```
    var contentManager = WorkContext.Resolve<IContentManager>();
    IEnumerable<ContentItem> products = contentManager.Query("product").List();
    ContentItem expT = contentManager.Get(24);
    var test = expT.As<BodyPart>().Text;
```

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/content-types

Comment: Please, no. Don't retrieve contents from views. That code belongs in a controller action or a driver. Never, ever in the view.

Comment: So I guess what's wrong here is where the code is. So I guess the same approach is possible if it was not the "Layout.cshtml" but controller or a drive. I could edit the answer not to direct towards the "Layout.cshtml". :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Bertrand !(Edited my answer). Hope u could upvote my answer now. :)

Comment: The code sample is still incorrect in that you would not have the @'s and you would not resolve dependencies from code.